# How can I fix "Could not GET jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/dagger/dagger-android-processor/2.35.1/dagger-android-processor-2.35.1.pom"?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm practicing **Dagger 2** from this tutorial:
[vogella.com Dagger tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html#exercise_androiddagger).

But I got this error while running my **Android** project:

**Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/dagger/dagger-android-processor/2.35.1/dagger-android-processor-2.35.1.pom'**

How can I fix this issue?

This is my build.gradle Module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vogella.android.dagger2simple"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.35.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.35.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.35.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace jcenter() with mavenCentral() in all your build.gradle files.

As mentioned in migrating away from [JCenter guide](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2021/02/04/migratingjcenter/)